# Sitecore error "Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent."

Tags: sitecore-client, wffm, placeholders

I am trying to Insert a new form. When I am trying to select a placeholder for the form, following error is showing :

[image]

when I had installed the WFFM, I went to "Restrict placeholder" and added my placeholder, like below [image]

I googled the issue, but coudn't find any relevant solution to this.

**So I got why this error is coming. I installed WFFM first in my sitecore instance, and then I installed SXA. DUring SXA installation, a popup came :**

[image]

and I chose "Side by Side" option and clicked "Apply to all".
After installation, when In add form, it show the error during selection of placeholder.
If I choose Overwrite option, SXA will not install.

Any suggestion what to do?

Comment: Did you try to check if you have written some cookie modification code or you have extended a pipeline? Because as per the links below it may be that your pipeline is executing & trying to modify the cookie but it does that before it the request for the form already sent the headers back to the client & you get this error. You can get more idea from these links:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287331/server-cannot-modify-cookies-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-how-fix
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383169/server-cannot-set-status-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-iis7-5

Comment: Also, check if you have somewhere the URL redirecting code, and you are trying to set the cookie after it then you also get this error.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and SXA?

Comment: Sitecore 8.2 update 1 and SXA 1.2